# What is the best way to track a game's constantly updating log file with python?

Tags: python, json, logging, updating

Maybe this is too broad of a question, but I just want to know how to start. I want to make a certain program for Marvel SNAP. If you're familiar with the game, you know that trackers already exist despite the game coming out only last year. However, there is no info for Python and this is the only language I (barely) know. In fact, I can't find any info on log tracking via Python. This is a turn based game so the log file updates per turn but doesn't update constantly like a live action game or whatnot. I won't post the log file because it's huge, but it seems like the game log is all inside the "GameState.json" file. I know Python can track json files but I don't know how to get that to happen on a file that's "open" while a game is running and updating constantly. I'm sorry if this is too vague but I'm looking for a place to start, does the Python json parser work on updating files, and if so how to best do that, and if not if there's anything I can do to track this.

If you have more questions I am happy to respond and try and let you know what I want to do, but the broad question is does

```
j = json.load(c.open(json_file_path, 'r', 'utf-8-sig'))
    for i in j:
        print(i)
```

work for a constantly updating file while the game is running? Thanks in advance.

Comment: as Kato said the `GameState.json` have almost the last turn info only and it is not live, just updates after you click the `claim rewards` after game ends. the `ErrorLog.txt` file though, can be helpful based on what you want, because it has **ALMOST** all the info about game, not all the info, but it is live and you can read the file as a stream and put the marker in the end so when you want to get updates it knows from where the seeking should start.

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for a way to parse this file and do my own stuff, but it seems that GameState.json only updates after the game ends and there's actually no data being written mid-game. However there's a file ErrorLog.txt on `AppData\LocalLow\Second Dinner\SNAP` which has each action that happens in the game.

You can even left this file open and see it being updated live. From a brief search I found that the Hearthstone version of the Untapped tracker does something very similar.

Comment: I dug up all those files a lot, but the question is how current trackers work? they constantly read the json files in `nvprod` folder which it seems to be for uploading purpose (cuz they contain basically nothing), they never access the `ErrorLog` file or any other file in that folder for what that matters. I feel either the `GameState.json` file changes so fast (which is impossible because the dates on the file only changes when the game ends) or they use the game memory because even if they used the error log, it does not contain graveyard and some other info that trackers have!